# Can I use three 2-wire Romex runs to wire 5 switches?

Tags: wiring

I am installing new lighting in my garage.  I have a 4-gang box that will house 5 switches (3 standard dimmers and one light/fan combo).  Rather than running 5 romex runs, I'd like to run 3, per this schematic. Can I safely wire it like such:
[image]

UPDATE: To clarify based on responses to my question, to be in compliance with nec 300.3, I'll need to use ENT/"smurf tubing" with THHN rather than Romex, like so, correct?: [image]

Answer (score 11):

### That'd be a Code violation -- use THHNs in ENT instead

Trying to split runs across cables like that is considered a NEC violation (300.3(B)/310.10(H)) due to stray magnetic fields leaking out from the cables that can heat up any ferrous metal that happens to be in the way.  I would instead use a length of ½" ENT (smurf tube) with individual THHN wires in it to connect the two boxes; this is no more expensive than NM, and very possibly cheaper even.

Answer (score 8):

No, that's a 300.3 violation because related wires aren't in the same cable.  You have hot going out one cable and coming back another cable. That makes inbalance currents in both cables.   That is a requirement with AC power, because of their magnetic fields.  DC magnetic fields just sit there like a refrigerator magnet but AC magnetic fields are pulsing constantly - that's why transformers work on AC and not DC.  Current in an AC cable needs to be equal and opposite per cable, so that these magnetic fields cancel each other out.

This happens all the time, when you have a bathroom fan-light-heater and need hot, neutral and 3 switched hots.  The right answer there, and here, is to run conduit such as "smurf tube" and run individual THHN conductors in the conduit.  That is literally what that stuff is for.  It satisfies 300.3 since they're all in the same conduit.

1/2" conduit is good for up to 9 wires - you'll have ground, always-hot, neutral, and 5 switched-hot, so that's 8.

If you're wondering "what's with all this 'neutral' stuff, switches don't need neutral" nope, you have a "switch loop" there (x5) and switch loops require neutral now.  NEC 404.2(C).   However if you run conduit, all you have to do is reserve space in the conduit for a neutral - you don't have to actually pull it.

If you also need physical protection due to being in a garage, then use EMT or Sched 80 PVC instead of Smurf.  Sched 40 PVC is worthless for physical protection.

Comment: Thank you both (Harper - Reinstate Monica, and ThreePhaseEel)! So, I only need to pull one neutral wire (and don't even technically need it as long as I leave space)?  I assume that all the THHN should be solid wire? The run between the junction box and the switch box will be in the wall (OSB over the studs).  The runs from the junction box to the various fixtures will be exposed. Can I use aluminum flex conduit for that or does it have to be EMT or schedule 80? Thanks again.

Comment: @ZekeBean THHN can be solid or stranded. What it can't be is sloppily installed, and stranded THHN is very hard to get on side screws non-sloppily. It is not allowed in backstabs (nor is any #12 wire).  Stranded works fine with screw-and-clamp.  If the wall will be covered, then you have physical protection and can use smurf.

Comment: Thanks.  For the uncovered portion (from the junction box to the fixture will be run along the top plate, ceiling joist, and ridge beam) is aluminum flex conduit sufficient?

Comment: @ZekeBean -- considering it's up in the ceiling, exposed ENT should be fine there